# JSViews Merge id with string to get unique id

Tags: jsviews

I have an array which I am iterating over using

```
{{for}}
```

in the loop, I am creating various elements, one of which I need to generate unique Ids for include one of the variables in the array (Id)

so for example:

```
<div id="post-123">...
```

I have tried:

```
<div data-link="id{post-:Id}">...
```

and

```
div data-link="id{'post-':Id}">...
```

and

```
<div id="post-" data-link="id{merge:Id}">...
```

however none of these work.

if I omit the string and just use:

```
<div data-link="id{:Id}">...
```

it sets the Id just fine. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links talk of data-linking to attributes:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax
- http://www.jsviews.com/#link-elemattribs
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/attributes

The standard syntax is

```
data-link="attributeName{:dataPathOrExpression}"
```

In your case attributeName is `id`.

`dataPathOrExpression` can be any expression, so here you need it to be the `Id` value concatenated with (preceded by) the string `'post-'`, so you need to write:

```
<div data-link="id{:'post-' + Id}">...
```

or, equivalently

```
<div data-link='id{:"post-" + Id}'>...
```

You don't want to put anything between the `{` and `:`. The tag is `{:` (http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag) - and the only thing you can put between those characters is a converter name such as `myCvt`, as in: `id{myCvt:...}`.

---

That said, if your `Id` values are not changing observably, then you don't need to data-link the `id` and you can instead write:

```
<div id="post-{{:Id}}">...
```

just as you would if you were rendering the template as a JsRender template, without data binding.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't grasped that the colon was part of the tag.